# How to preload associations of STI models in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

#### My Problem

Imagine I've got those models:

```rb
class Absence << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Vacation << Absence
  belongs_to :vacation_contingent
end

class Illness << Absence; end
```

Now I want to retrieve all absences with

```rb
absences = Absence.where(user: xxx)
```

and iterate over the vacation contingents

```rb
vacations = absences.select { |absence| absence.is_a?(Vacation)
vacations.each { |vacation| puts vacation.vacation_contingent.xxx }
```

Now I've got 1 database query for those absences and 1 for each vacation_contingent -> bad

PS: I use `Absence.where` instead of `Vacation.where` because I want to do other things with those `absences`.

#### What I tried

1. Of course

```rb
Absence.where(user: xxx).includes(:vacation_contingent)
# -> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError Exception: Association named 'vacation_contingent' was not found`
```

2. 

```rb
vacations = Vactions.where(user: xxx).includes(:vacation_contingent)
other_absences = Absence.where(user: xxx).where.not(type: 'Vacation')
```

But this one is ugly and I've got 1 database query more than I want to because I'm fetchting the absences 2 times.

3.

```rb
absences = Absence.where(user: xxx)
vacations = absences.select { |absence| absence.is_a?(Vacation)
preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
preloader.preload(vacations, :vacation_contingent)
# -> ArgumentError Exception: missing keywords: :records, :associations
# -> (The initializer changed)
```

4. 

```rb
absences = Absence.where(user: xxx)
vacations = absences.select { |absence| absence.is_a?(Vacation)
preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records: vacations, associations: %i[vacation_contingent])
# -> This line does nothing on it's own
preloader.call
# -> This just executes SELECT "vacation_contingents".* FROM "vacation_contingents" vacation.size times
preloader.preload
# -> Does the same as .call
# -> And this doesn't even preload anything. When executing
vacations.first.vacation_contingent
# -> then the database is being asked again
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution 2 looks to me the best you can do with ActiveRecord.

If you want only one request, you could do it with raw SQL; Something like :

```
Absence.connection.select_all(%{SELECT * 
                                FROM absences
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN vacation_contingents ON absences.vacation_contingents_id = vacation_contingents.id
                                WHERE absences.user_id = ?", user_xxx.id})
```

It will return [ActiveRecord::Result](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) with a line for each `Absence`, and both the columns of `Absence` and `VacationContingent`

Comment: Even if I manage to build `Vacation`s and `VacationContingent`s out of this `ActiveRecord::Result` like `vacations, other_absences, vacation_logs = magic(active_record_result)`, a call to `vacations.first.vacation_contingent` would still query the database. I don't see a way to get this working without implementing a lot of custom logic.

I'm going to stick to solution 2 for now, thanks